# NodeJS/Forever archive logs

Tags: node.js, forever, winston

I am using [forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) to run my node application.  When I start forever I specify where to write the logs.  I also specify to append to the log.  Problem here is that my log is going to grow out of control over the course of months.

Is there any way to archive/roll logs on an interval, i.e. every day roll/archive what is in the log file to another file (i.e. server-2013-3-5.log).  That way I can delete/move off old log files as needed.

I have just started looking into using Winston for my logger and I have not come across anything there that would help.

Any ideas?

Comment: How did you solve it in the end?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

forever itself doesn't support log rotation and log rotation is still a [pending feature request](https://github.com/flatiron/winston/issues/10) for Winston.

You can use `logrotate` which is included in most Linux distributions and is used for rotating system log files, as well as used by other software like Apache.

Add a file to `/etc/logrotate.d/`

```
/path/to/server.log {
  daily         # how often to rotate
  rotate 10     # max num of log files to keep
  missingok     # don't panic if the log file doesn't exist
  notifempty    # ignore empty files
  compress      # compress rotated log file with gzip
  sharedscripts # postrotate script (if any) will be run only once at the end, not once for each rotated log
  copytruncate  # needed for forever to work properly
  dateext       # adds date to filename 
  dateformat %Y-%m-%d.
}
```

See [more `logrotate` examples](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/logrotate-examples/).

Comment: Log rotation is now possible with Winston: https://github.com/flatiron/winston/pull/205

Comment: `sharedscripts`: "The sharedscripts means that the postrotate script will only be run once(after the old logs have been  compressed), not  once for each log which is rotated." [man logrotate](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html)

Comment: @JCM How does one configure forever to use this new feature in Winston, though? Do I have to switch from command-line usage to programmatic usage of forever?

Comment: @sheldonh idk, you probably should open an issue in the forever project asking that.

Comment: With this configuration my forever.log is still growing indefinitely, the logrotate only copies the file and doesn't touch the original log file which keeps on growing..., so this solution does not solve the question completely. Especially this part *"my log is going to grow out of control"*